# Binding lost (after click) in angular js small example

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I have a very small application in Angular JS. It's placed inside a bigger rails application, but I don't see too much interaction. The angular application, allows the user to interact with a group of categories. As easy as:

```
var angular_app = angular.module('angular_app', []);

angular_app.config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider, $cookieStore) {
//Protection
}]);

angular_app.controller('CategoriesController', function ($scope, $http) {

$scope.isEditing = false;
$scope.categoryName = '';

$http.get('/api/categories').success(function(data) {
    //We use this to data-bind with the HTML placed below
    $scope.categories = data;
});

$scope.addNewCategory = function() {
    ...
}

$scope.editCategory = function(index) {
    if (!index)
        return;

    var selectedCategory = $scope.categories[index];

    // With ng-show, we make visible the part of the UI 
    // that should be used for editing
    $scope.isEditing = true;
}

$scope.cancelEditCategory = function() {
    $scope.isEditing = false;
}

$scope.deleteCategory = function(index) {
    ...
}

});

angular.element(document).ready(function() {
    angular.bootstrap(document, ['angular_app']);
});
```

The idea is that the information is shown in a list, and we have an 'edit' button that allows the user to see other part of the UI that will let him perform changes.

```
<div ng-controller="CategoriesController">
 <div ng-show='isEditing' class="popup_menu">
   DIV FOR EDITING
  </div>

  <ul>
     <li ng-repeat="category in categories">
        <a href="#" ng-click='deleteCategory($index)'>[X]</a>
        <a href="#" ng-click='editCategory($index)'>[E]</a>{{ category.name }}
      </li>
  </ul>

   <input type="text" id="categoryTextBox" ng-model="categoryName"/>
   <button id="submit" ng-click='addNewCategory()'>New category</button>

</div>
```

When I'm clicking the edit button, the corresponding part of the UI gets visible, but just after that, something happens, and the ul that should render the list, looses completely the binding, just showing something like:

```
 [X] [E]{{ category.name }}
```

When it must be showing:

```
[X] [E]computer science
[X] [E]politics
[X] [E]news
```

(Which is what I have in the scope). It happens a few after the click (and works for a sec). **No errors on the console**, no interactions with other libraries (as far as I can see).

Thanks!

Comment: See the browser console log for errors.

Comment: Thanks!, but the error log was empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that I should have been more careful with the links:

```
<a href="#" ng-click='deleteCategory($index)'>[X]</a>
<a href="#" ng-click='editCategory($index)'>[E]</a>{{ category.name }}
```

Don't know exactly how this works, but seems that if the link has his href attribute, a GET request is made against 127.0.0.1, breaking in some way the angular code. If you put them like:

```
<a ng-click='deleteCategory($index)'>[X]</a>
<a ng-click='editCategory($index)'>[E]</a>{{ category.name }}
```

The problem will be solved. Thanks all for reading and helping!

Answer (score 2):

**Turbolinks**

I have no experience with `Angular`, but perhaps your problem could be to do with [`Turbolinks`](https://github.com/rails/turbolinks) - this is a way of Rails loading the `<body>` tag of a page only - keeping the `<head>` intact.

Turbolinks is notorious for Javascript on Rails, as each time you reload your `<body>` without reloading the `<head>` part of your page, all your JS bindings are going to disappear. The solution to this, in normal JS, is to use [JQuery / Javascript `delegation`](http://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate), and delegate from the `document` object:

```
$(document).on("action", "delegated_object", function(){
 ...
});
```

Apologies if this does not work - it's a common issue for us, but as I have no experience with `Angular`, I don't know if it's going to help you or not.

Comment: I second this answer. Turbolink is the new devil, disable it and live happily.